The asymptotic expansion of the partial sums of a divergent series
I want to obtain an asymptotic expansion for the partial sum $$S_N:=\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1}$$ with a remainder term of $o(1)$, but I encountered difficulties when determining the constant term.
Specifically, I want to obtain$$S_N = f(N)+C+o(1)$$where$f(N)$is an unbounded function and $C$ is a constant.I tried using the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula, but this only provides an estimate for the constant $C$, and I couldn't accurately determine it. However, considering general cases, like with the harmonic series, it seems that constants such as Euler's constant $\gamma$ also lack a straightforward way to be expressed precisely.
However, in Stirling's formula, the constant term $\log(2\pi)$ can be obtained through certain specific methods, so I wonder if there are other ways to obtain a closed-form expression for the constant term $C$ in this partial sum as well.

the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+ \sqrt x}  $  is $2 \sqrt x - 2 \log (1 + sqrt x).$  Your sum, minus this, does seem to approach a constant...See if I can find it, $\zeta(1/2)$  shows up as the difference between a sum and an integral.  Found it, as one would expect, sum minus integral for $1 / \sqrt n$

@Gary That should be the answer

@leonbloy OK, I posted an answer.

I do not think there is a simple closed form for the constant. It certainly holds that
$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^N {\frac{1}{{\sqrt n  + 1}}}  = 2\sqrt N  - 2\log (\sqrt N  + 1) + C + \frac{1}{{2(\sqrt N  + 1)}} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{N^{3/2} }}} \right)$$
with
$$
C = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt 2 \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sqrt t }}{{(t + \sqrt {2t}  + 1)({\rm e}^{2\pi t}  - 1)}}{\rm d}t} = 0.64643929655673\ldots\;.
$$
This result can be deduced by an application of the Abel–Plana formula.
